# Error Creating Google Cloud Dataproc Cluster - no access to initialization proxy script

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-dataproc, google-iam

I am trying to create my first Google Cloud Dataproc cluster using the following command:

```sh
gcloud dataproc clusters create hive-cluster    \ 
    --scopes sql-admin  \   
    --image-version 1.3  \   
    --initialization-actions "gs://goog-dataproc-${PROJECT}:${REGION}:hive-metastore" \
    --master-machine-type n1-standard-1 \
    --master-boot-disk-size 15 \
    --num-workers 2 \
    --worker-machine-type n1-standard-1 \
    --worker-boot-disk-size 15 \
    --region us-east1 \
    --zone us-east1-b
```

However, I get the following error:

```
    Dataproc could not validate the initialization action using the service-owned service accounts. Cluster creation may still succeed if the initialization action is accessible from GCE VMs.
    Reason: service-1456309104734317@dataproc-accounts.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.get access to goog-dataproc-initialization-actions-us-east1/cloud-sql-proxy/cloud-sql-proxy.sh.
    Waiting for cluster creation operation...done.
    ERROR: (gcloud.dataproc.clusters.create) Operation [projects/traits-seater-824109/regions/us-east1/operations/5b36fb82-ade2-3d5f-a6bd-cb1a206bb54e] failed: Multiple Errors:
     - Error downloading script 'gs://goog-dataproc-initialization-actions-us-east1/cloud-sql-proxy/cloud-sql-proxy.sh': 1456309104734317-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.get access to goog-dataproc-initialization-actions-us-east1/cloud-sql-proxy/cloud-sql-proxy.sh.
```

I checked the permissions in IAM and gave the storage->Object viewer roles to the service accounts mentioned in the error message above but I still get the same error. 
Any suggestions how to get past this error?

Comment: There might be a typo in your stackoverflow question where you deleted part of your initialization-actions flag and mixed it with your --metadata flag, though I think that's only a typo in the question posted here instead of the command you actually ran since the erro rmessage references the correct init action path.

Comment: We have resolved issues with permissions to regional buckets, please retry your command.

Comment: Thanks @IgorDvorzhak! That did it. The file now has public access now and the command runs fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be a temporary issue with permissions settings on Dataproc's regionally-hosted versions of the initialization actions -- long term these regional copies are indeed what you should be using for better isolating regional reliability of the init actions and also to avoid cross-region copying of init actions, but in the meantime, you can use the shared "global" copy of the init action instead:

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create hive-cluster    \ 
--initialization-actions gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/cloud-sql-proxy/cloud-sql-proxy.sh \
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem may come from the [`scopes`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataproc/clusters/create#--scopes) you provided when creating the cluster. You only restrict your cluster to access the `sql-admin` API (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.admin).

You may need to add the `storage-ro` scope (or https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only) :

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create hive-cluster \ 
    --scopes sql-admin,storage-ro \
    [...]
```

Without the `storage-ro` scope, even if the bucket `goog-dataproc-initialization-actions-us-east1` is public, I think that the Dataproc cluster will not be able to retrieve the file from GCS.

Comment: Good thought, though Dataproc nowadays is expected to automatically insert the base requisite scopes automatically, including especially the necessary storage scopes, and also the Dataproc-hosted init actions are expected to be public-read -- there might be something else going on here.

Comment: Is it documented somewhere (the fact that Dataproc insert the base scopes automatically)? Before answering, I have been looking for this in the docs but could not find it :(

Comment: The scope wasn't the issue. As mentioned by  Igor Dvorzhak in the comments above the permissions for the regional buckets was updated so that my account can now access the file.

Comment: @norbjd excellent question, it appears this somehow slipped through the cracks, so the only way to discover this would be comparing the list of scopes in "gcloud dataproc clusters describe" when no scopes are specified and when a single scope is specified. I've filed a request to add the information to https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/service-accounts

Comment: For reference, the following information will be added to that page:

Comment: If any custom scopes are specified, Dataproc will use the combined set of user-specified scopes with the following minimum set of scoped needed by Dataproc:

    - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud.useraccounts.readonly
    - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write
    - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write

Comment: If no service-account scopes are specified, Dataproc will use the following default set of scopes:

    - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery
    - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigtable.admin.table
    - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigtable.data
    - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud.useraccounts.readonly
    - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control
    - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write
    - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write